# How to access and manage block stored data

Tags: c++, performance, design-patterns, data-structures, iterator

**What I want to do:** I need to store cell data in block-wise form, that is

*cell_member1[cell0] .. cell_member1[cellN]  ...  cell_memberM[cell0] .. cell_memberM[cellN]*

Then I need to access this data efficiently and, if possible, using a nice syntax. It would be great if I could define the data to be stored easily, i.e. by defining an object with members as the data that I want to store and passing it to some "magic" that does everything for me.

**Motivation:** why I need to do it this way? Cache trashing. In some inner loops only some members of the objects are accessed. Wasting half of a cache-line with unused memory is not an option for my application. I could store pointers in the objects that point to some sequential memory region. This wastes memory and forces me to use a different syntax in this regions.

**How I'm currently doing it:** I have a container of the form:

```
template<class T> struct Container {
  char* data;
  Container(const int n) {
    data = new char[n*T::spaceRequirements()]; //< Data stored "block-wise"
    new(data) typename T::Flags[n]; //< Flags stored "cell-wise"
  }
  /// Destructor ommited for briefness.
};
```

in which I store data for some cells of type T. I need some flags per cell and right now I'm using std::bitset to store them which means that I need to store this bitsets in cell-wise form:

*cell_member1[cell0] ... cell_memberM[cell0] ... cell_member1[cellN] .. cell_memberM[cellN]*

I am describing how much data per cell needs to be stored in the following class, which also provides access to the data:

```
template<int nd> struct CellAccessor {
  /// Cell flags are stored cell-wise:
  typedef std::bitset<64> Flags;
  enum { DELETE = 0, ///< Cell marked for deletion
         REFINE = 1 ///< Cell marked for refinement
         //...
  }; ///< Enum for the flags.
  static inline Flags& flags(const int cellId) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<Flags*>(data + sizeof(Flags)*cellId); }
  template<int pId> static inline Flags::reference flags(const int cellId) {
    return flags(cellId)[pId]; } //< Cell-wise access to the properties

  /// The rest of the data is stored block-wise:
  static inline int& order(const int cellId) { ///< One int field.
    return *reinterpret_cast<int*>
        (data + maxNoCells*sizeof(Flags) + sizeof(int)*cellId);}

  /// Coordinate vector with nd components:
  static inline double& coordinates(const int cellId, const int i) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<double*>
        (data + maxNoCells*(sizeof(Flags)+sizeof(int))
         + maxNoCells*i*sizeof(double) + sizeof(double)*cellId); }
  template<int i> static inline double& coordinates(const int cellId) {
    return *reinterpret_cast<double*>
        (data +maxNoCells*(sizeof(Flags)+sizeof(int)+i*sizeof(double))
         + sizeof(double)*cellId); }

  /// Total amount of memory to allocate per cell: (used by Container)
  static inline int spaceRequirements() { return
        sizeof(Flags) // Flags
        + sizeof(int) // order
        + nd*sizeof(double) // coordinates
        ;}

  /// Constructor gets pointer to the beginning of the container 
  /// and the offset for the member variables:
  CellAccessor(char* d, int n){data = d; maxNoCells = n;}
 private:
  static char* data;  ///< Pointer to the beginning of the container.
  static int maxNoCells;  ///< Cell offset for the member variables.
};
template<int nd> char* CellAccessor<nd>::data = nullptr;
template<int nd> int CellAccessor<nd>::maxNoCells = 0;
```

And I use it like this:

```
int main() {
  int maxNoCells = 10000;   ///< Maximum number of cells (=cell offset).
  typedef CellAccessor<2> A;
  Container< A > cellData(maxNoCells);  ///< Allocate cell data.
  A cells(cellData.data,maxNoCells);  ///< Provides access to cell data.

  for(int i = 0; i < maxNoCells; ++i){
    cells.flags<A::DELETE>(i) = i%2==0 ? true : false;
    cells.flags<A::REFINE>(i) = i%2==0 ? false : true;
    cells.coordinates(i,0) = i;
    cells.coordinates<1>(i) = -((double)i);
    cells.order(i) = 2;
  }
}
```

**Pros:**

- The data is in block-wise form, which is what I needed.
- The syntax is ok.

**Problems:**

- My classes are doing too much: providing access to the data for the users, providing how much data needs to be stored for the containers, providing how the data should be moved/copied/swaped for my data structures (which are trees...)...
- I can't use STL algorithms without iterators. I've implemented iterators by making them store the cell index and reimplementing the CellAccessor class inside them (bad! DRY!).
- Bitset is still being stored in cell-wise form. I could re-implement bitset for my block-wise data structure...
- data and maxNoCells are static variables, but I could make them normal member variables if required.

**Question:** is there any efficient way to store "objects" (or what we conceptually understand by objects) in block-wise form and access them as if they were stored in a std container such as vector?

Comment: Take a look at `std::aligned_storage` for a start.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling thanks, looks interesting.

Comment: For those like me who don't get it, why is std::vector wrong for this job ?

Comment: @Jem Because of cache trashing. In a std::vector<POD>, the members of the POD are aligned continuously in memory. This means that when you access one member, 8 words of memory will be copied to the cache line starting at that member, even tho you would be only using the first 2 of those words. That means memory bandwith is reduced by a factor of 4. Modern CPUs are memory bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a style of a "COLUMN BASED" memory access

You can easily implement it using `std::vector` as your column type or create your own "column" type with your own underlying memory management - but `std::vector` should work just fine

Now once you have your column type you create your "TABLE" type.

In a way your table cab be just a vector of vectors. You can of course wrap it up in order to get better looking accessors (If you want to access by row (object) first and column (property) after.

This is I think the best general approach.

Even In your specific case - since you want to save memory using bit length flags, as mentioned by Bart van Ingen Schenau you can use a `vector<bool>` so the general approach stands

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't see the forest at such a low level. I just rewrote the whole thing using std::vectors. It looks pretty clean. In the future I'll implement a custom allocator and that should do it (I've said this many times and never came even close to it :D :'( ).

Comment: @gnzlbg Glad to help. Why not mark the question as answered then? :-) I understand about allocators, Don't know anyone who really likes implementing them...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that understood correctly the question. It looks like you are trying to allocate data in a sequential array of bytes. Why?
but in any case you could do it simply by using arrays:

```
class Cell {
   std::bitset<64> flags;
   int order;
   double coordinates[2];
}

int main() {
   const int maxNoCells = 10000;
   Cell cells[maxNoCells];

   for(int i = 0; i < maxNoCells; i++) {
       cells[i].flags = ...;
       cells[i].coordinates[0] = i;
       cells[i].coordinates[1] = -i;
       cells[i].order=2;
   }
}
```

and then cast it to (char *)cells  if needed. Your classes will be allocated in a segmented fashion in a contiguous memory strip. You could use it for read/write/net. The only issue is that you have to take care of 32/64 bit alignments in particular if it is
shared between different architectures.

Here is another version which would be a bit better for caching if you insist on using different fields in separate loops:

```
template<int size>
class CellAccessor {
    std::bitset<64> flags[size];
    int order[size];
    double coordinates[size][2];
 public:
    std::bitset<64> &getFlags(int id) {
        return flags[id];
    }
    int &getOrder(int id) {
        return order[id];
    }
    ...
 }


main() {

    CellAccessor<10000> ca;

    for(...i++) {
        ca.getOrder(i) = 2;
        ca.getCoordinates(i)[0] = i;
        ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've added a "motivation" to the question.

Comment: i just modified my code to better reflect your proposal. It still servers the purpose even for the cache optimization. With this definitions it is very packed and does not waist any memory on padding. Your approach might be more interesting if you are trying to save on padding ant your architecture allows unalligned access to data. But in general if there is an issue shift fields around to reduce overall size of the struct.

Comment: And just a hint, even if you go with your proposal, you could overload 'operator [] (int)' in CellAccessor class, so that the syntax would look much better.

Comment: You are right, in your code the data is very tightly packed and you don't waste any memory. The problem is that when you access order in your code, the cache line will be partially filled with data from coordinates. That means that in a loop in which I am only using order, and not coordinates, I am wasting memory bandwith (not the same as memory!).

Comment: then just put the fields in separate arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I would use parrallel arrays to meet the requirements:

```
template <int nd>
class CellAccessor {
public:
    enum { DELETE = 0, ///< Cell marked for deletion
           REFINE = 1, ///< Cell marked for refinement
           //...
           NUM_FLAGS
    }; ///< Enum for the flags.
    CellAccessor(int numCells) {
        for (int i=0; i<NUM_FLAGS; i++) { m_flags[i] = new bool[numCells]; }
        m_order = new int[numCells];
        for (int i=0; i<nd; i++) { m_coordinates[i] = new double[numCells]; }
    }
    // Destructor, copy-constructor & assignment operator omitted for brevity

    template<int F> inline bool& flags(const int cellId) {
        return m_flags[F][cellId]; }
    inline bool& flags(const int cellId, int flag) {
        return m_flags[flag][cellId]; }
    inline int& order(const int cellId) {
        return m_order[cellId]; }
    template<int i> inline double& coordinates(const int cellId) {
        return m_coordinates[i][cellId]; }
    inline double& coordinates(const int cellId, int i) {
        return m_coordinates[i][cellId]; }

private:
    bool* m_flags[NUM_FLAGS];
    int*  m_order;
    double* m_coordinates[nd];
};
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! However, the memory requirements for the flags just grew from 1 bit to 4 bytes.

Comment: Furthermore, calling new for each array is not an option because it will likely result in a std::bad_alloc error. I explain: say you have 64Gb of ram and each of the arrays is a couple of Gb long. If you allocate a continuous block of memory for each array and new does not place them continuously after each other the "holes" in the memory layout will prevent you from from getting even close to those 64Gb of ram. You need to help new/malloc by allocating a huge chunk of memory first and passing them a pointer to where you want them to perform the allocation.

Comment: @gnzlbg: You can reduce the storage requirements by replacing the `bool*` with `std::vector<bool>`, which is optimised to only use a single bit per element. For the rest, that is the price you have to pay for wanting a memory layout that is not directly supported by C++.

Comment: Sadly I have to pay it. I was hoping that there was some generic library available that would provide me with such an abstaction given a class definition but it seems that is not the case.